# django-viewflow signal to work with a djangosignal

Tags: django-viewflow

I'm trying to set a `viewflow.Signal` to work with a `django.signal` but I just cannot. I've followed the examples included in the documentation but it just keeps failing:
[viewflow.Signal](http://docs.viewflow.io/viewflow_core_node.html#viewflow.nodes.Signal)

anyone knows how to set the set the `receiver` and the `task_loader`

---

I use a `django signal`  to trigger the `signal task` :

```
class FlowReg (Flow):
    start = ()
    enabled_signal = (
       flow.Signal(
       node_validation_signal, 
       receipt_created,
       task_loader = this.get_task).Next(this.join_val_tasks))

    def get_task(self, flow_task,  **kwargs):
        proc_id = kwargs['id']
        proc_to_work = self.__class__.process_class.objects.get(node_process=proc_id)
        task_to_return = proc_to_work.get_task(FlowReg.enabled_signal)
        return task_to_return
```

and I don't know how to do it to not use **`task_loader`**

Comment: What is your sample code, and what exception do you have?

Comment: code added, thanks